# MS Excel: indicate if there are matches in 2 columns

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns of data. I want to compare column B with column A and display if there is a match in column C, eg:

[image]

So basically, if the value of the cell I am looking at in B has a match anywhere in column A, return 'Match', else return 'No Match'.

I've looked up how to do this and found VLOOKUP but have not been able to get it working. I've got tried:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,A, FALSE), "No Match")
```

But this just returns No Match no matter what.

Would anyone know of the correct way to do this?

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),"Not match","Match")`

Comment: @Andy, thanks. Want to make that an answer?

Comment: You are welcome.It is my plesure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit simpler than nesting Match and ISError is simply counting. If the result is 0 then there is no match.

```
=if(countif(A:A,B1),"match","no match")
```

You don't even have to compare the result of the count with a number. Any number greater than 0 will be TRUE, a zero will be FALSE.